# Function works on own, but fails with multiple files in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a function that works with an individual file on the R console. When I run it through my shiny app, it also works. However, when I try to run multiple files in the shiny app, incorrect data is inputted into the excel spreadsheet. I receive the following error:

> Warning: Error in while: argument is of length zero
> 116: FUN [helper2.R#18]
> 115: lapply
> 114: reactive:ediorderlist [C:\Users\carri\Documents\Test\EasternEDI/app.R#101]
> 98: ediorderlist
> 96: renderTable [C:\Users\carri\Documents\Test\EasternEDI/app.R#120]
> 95: func
> 82: origRenderFunc
> 81: output$ediTable
> 1: shiny::runApp
> Warning: Error in while: argument is of length zero
> 99:

My shiny code is as follows

```
ediorderlist<-reactive({
    
    validate(need(input$excelfile !="","select excel file"))
    if(!is.null(input$ediorder)){
      edidf<-lapply(input$ediorder$datapath, createEDIrecord, excelfile=input$excelfile$datapath)  
      bind_rows(edidf)
    }
  })
```

The most likely cause is this while loop. Again, it runs just fine with one file. When multiple files are sent via shiny, the output from the first file is incorrect and the error is thrown.

```
orders<-data.frame("PO"=NA,"delDate"=NA,"QTY"=NA,"UNIT"="CA","Price"=NA,"UPC"=NA,"DPCI"=NA)
  i<-1
  ordermarker<-1
  while(i<=length(lastpage)){
    temp<-unlist(ediorders[[i]])
    temp<-gsub("\\s+"," ",temp)
    orderstart<-grep("N4\\*",temp)
    orderend<-grep("SE\\*",temp)
    itemqtyline<-grep("PO1\\*",temp)
    itemlines<-grep("CB\\*",temp)
    j<-orderstart
    itemmarker<-1
    
    while(j<=orderend){
      while(itemmarker<=length(itemlines)){
        QtyPrice<-str_split(temp[itemqtyline[itemmarker]],"\\*")
        qty<-QtyPrice[[1]][3]
        amount<-QtyPrice[[1]][5]
        DPCI<-QtyPrice[[1]][8]
        UPC<-QtyPrice[[1]][12]
        orders<-add_row(orders,PO=PO[i,1],delDate=deldate[i,1],QTY=qty,Price=amount,UPC=UPC,DPCI=DPCI,)
        itemmarker<-itemmarker+1
      }
      j<-j+1
      
      
    }
    i<-i+1
    
  }
```

Comment: It looks like there is a `while` statement in your `createEDIrecord` function on line 18 of your helper2.R script, that is getting a nullish value. Take a look at what you are using in that while.

Comment: Do you know why it would work when I run the function with one file, but not with multiple files?  The while loop functions on its own, just not when I send multiple files through with the lapply.

Comment: It's difficult to say based on this alone.  I'd suggest using `debug` on your `createEDIrecord` on place a `browser()`  call within the function, then run it and see whats going on.

Comment: The issue was when I called data from the Excel file, it was detecting an integer as a date. I removed the `detectDates` from the `read.xlsx` function, the function worked as it should.